# Input-Component: React does not recognize the prop on a DOM Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am facing an issue when I try to set the state of a component in the Input field. I have tried by setting the Object values in the constructor but that didn't work either. If I remove the prop the input field is not getting any value. I have posted my JS code below.

Input Component:

```
            <div className="form__group">
              <input
                className="form__field"
                id={props.name}
                name={props.name}
                type={props.inputtype}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.handleChange}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                {...props}
              />
              <label htmlFor={props.name} className="form__label">{props.placeholder}</label>
            </div>
```

JSX Code:

```
          <Input
            inputtype={"text"}
            title={"Full Name : "}
            name={"name"}
            value={this.state.newUser.name}
            handleChange={this.handleInput}
            placeholder={"Enter your Name"}
          />{" "}
```

JS Code:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newUser: {
        name: "",
        age: "",
        gender: "",
        skills: [],
        about: ""
      },
this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}
  handleInput(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        newUser: {
          ...prevState.newUser,
          [name]: value
        }
      }),
      () => console.log(this.state.newUser)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you talking ? In the component ? if i use this in component, then it wouldnt be able to get the this there

Comment: Try this while setting your state `this.setState({
            newUser:{
                ...this.state.newUser,
                [name]:value
            }
        })`  UPDATED

Comment: @Nane Sorry, but still the same error... As far as i have researched it comes from the Component as the props are being set at component level.

Comment: Hey can you share a codesandbox it will be really helpful

Comment: @Nane: Sure. Give me sometime, i will setup everything online

Comment: @Nane: I have setup it up on sandbox 
https://pv6gi.csb.app/

Comment: Share the sandbox Url which has code

Comment: Oh Sorry for that... Here is that 
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-resonance-pv6gi

Comment: Hey, Everything seems to be working what state you have to update like is it `name`

Comment: Actually, there is no error as such, but just a warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

handleChange is passed on because of `{...props}`, and is not a valid for the input element.

If you spread out the props in the parameters:

```
const Input = ({ name, inputType, value, handleChange, placeholder, ...props}) => {
```

and then

```
<input
              className="form__field"
              id={name}
              name={name}
              type={inputType}
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              {...props}
/>
```

Comment: Now i got to know, that the component expects every attr in html as a parameter

Comment: You could of course just keep it like it was, and just remove {...props} from the input element. {...props} will just map out all the values in the props object as html attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a problem in your JSX (handleChange instead of onChange, but it is not the main thing)

So in my example your final code should look like this

```
handleInput = (input) => {
  this.setState({ newUser: { [input.target.name]: input.target.value } });
}

  <Input
    inputtype="text"
    title="Full Name : "
    name="name"
    value={this.state.newUser.name}
    onChange={this.handleInput}
    placeholder="Enter your Name"
  />
```

Comment: Ok so the logic you have implemented defers from my logic. Actually i wanted to make the component a dynamic component, where it would set the function from the prop itself. So thats why i have given the onChange in the component prop itself and then set it in my jsx.

Comment: I think that there is should be no problem about onChange if it is realized correctly in your dynamic Input component. Did you tried to change your handleClick to mine?